# Raspberry Pi Zero W access point sharing LAN thorough ethernet gadget

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w, gadget

I've recently wanted to do a project with the Raspberry Pi Zero.
Basically, I want to set up the Pi as an ethernet gadget for computers to be able to play games over WLAN. The computers have no wifi and each will have a Raspberry Pi. I need to make the Raspberry Pi's act like ethernet adapters to connect them together. The Raspberry Pi's would then connect to a wifi network that would allow them to create a wireless LAN. To get it to work, I would need multiple Pi's connecting to only one. I have more or less figured out how to set up the AP here: https://gist.github.com/ajfisher/a84889e64565d7a74888

The only problem I have is that the WLAN that the Pi's would create is not accessible through the ethernet gadget. How would I make it so that the WLAN is shared?

Comment: Just for understanding: you have several computer connected together over ethernet LAN using a switch to play games. To the switch is also connected your Raspberry Pi. How comes now wifi to play? For what do you want to use that?

Comment: The computers have no wifi. I need to make the Raspberry Pi's act like ethernet adapters to connect them together. The Raspberry Pi's would then connect to a wifi network that would allow them to create a wireless LAN.

Comment: You always write LAN in your question. That's a little bit confusing for me. Usually we distinguish between a LAN - devices connected with ethernet cables - and a WLAN - wireless LAN, no cables. Every computer should get a raspi to connect the computer to the shared WLAN, isn't it?

Comment: Yes sorry. By LAN, I mean WLAN.

Comment: again: every computer should get a raspi to connect the computer to the shared WLAN, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, Ingo. Just imagine the computer having no internet interfaces at all, and I want to use the Raspberry Pi as an ethernet adapter.

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly two ways to connect the gadgets to a common wifi network. First you can use routing but for a two way communication you must set static routes to each gadget and that is to much effort. The second way is to use bridging so the devices become member of the common network so as they where direct connected. Unfortunately Raspberry Pi does not support real bridging on wifi. But there is a possibility to use *proxy arp*. This will emulate a bridge on wifi. How to setup this you can look at [Workaround for a wifi bridge on a Raspberry Pi with proxy arp](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/88954/79866).