# Raspberry pi Proxy ARP wifi bridge + extra ethernet adapter

Tags: wifi, ethernet, bridge

Going through this thread:

[proxy ARP WiFi bridge Raspberry](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88954/workaround-for-a-wifi-bridge-on-a-raspberry-pi-with-proxy-arp/88955#88955)

Ingo´s solution is working fine for me but I´m looking for an extra... With this WiFi bridge, I want to use an added USB-Ethernet adapter (with a fixed IP address). Both the bridge and adapter work separately, but if I plug the cable in the new adapter, I lose the internet connection in my bridge. The strange thing is that I´m able to go until the router, but I can not go outside. And as I said before without any cable plugged in everything is working well.

Does anyone know how to avoid this problem?

Comment: I fixed some grammar, please double check that the question is still what you intended to ask.

Comment: I will have a look at it. It takes a little bit of time.

Comment: I have just setup a proxy arp router as described behind the link you have given in your question and then plugged in an additional USB-Ethernet adapter as you described. I have no problems even with a plugged in ethernet cable. The additional interface **eth1** is just down and doesn't matter and proxy arp is working. What have I to do to get the error? How do you set the static ip address? What have you done different from my setup?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give some advices to the specific problem asked in the question because I don't get further information from the comments. Maybe the wired connection with an additional USB-ethernet dongle is also connected to the same internet router than the wifi interface and there is a routing problem. But I will show how to use an additional wired connection to a different subnet.

First setup proxy arp as described at [Workaround for a wifi bridge on a Raspberry Pi with proxy arp](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88955/79866) and make sure it's working. That's the same setup used in the question. Then just plug in the USB-ethernet dongle with an ethernet cable to the subnet. With this setup you have to ensure that the new subnet is another one than the wifi has. For example if **wlan0** has got an ip address `192.168.50.182/24` by DHCP then **eth1** could be set to `192.168.10.60/24`. Configure **eth1** with this file:

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es
rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/networki/04-eth1.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=eth1
[Network]
Address=192.168.10.60/24
EOF
```

Then restart the network with the new setting:

```
rpi ~# systemctl daemon-reload
rpi ~# systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service
rpi ~# exit
rpi ~$
```

Now you can use interface **eth0** as faked "bridge" to the wifi subnet `192.168.50.0/24` and you can use interface **eth1** to connect the RasPi as normal client to subnet `192.168.10.0/24`.