# proxy arp / briding wlan0 and uap0

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-zero

I try to setup a raspberry zero as repeater.
First i used that guide :
[https://kaiuwe.hüber.de/raspberry-pi-wifi-repeater-ohne-adapter/](https://kaiuwe.h%C3%BCber.de/raspberry-pi-wifi-repeater-ohne-adapter/)

But it's not a real repeater , but setting up a secondary wlan with another ssid.
I need the same SSID that the zero is connected to , to be extended.
So i came up with the proxy arp guide :
[Workaround for a wifi bridge on a Raspberry Pi with proxy arp](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88954/workaround-for-a-wifi-bridge-on-a-raspberry-pi-with-proxy-arp)

But i cant get it up and running.

Is it possible to setup a zero like that ?

```
                            v---proy arp---v
(Device) <---wireless---> (uap0)[Zero W](wlan0) <--wireless--> (Hotspot) -->inet
```

Comment: **uap0** is usually used as interface of an access point. So what you want is an access point that is connected with a client connection (**wlan0**) to a another remote hotspot so the RasPi works as a repeater (you wrote it). Can you confirm this please?

Comment: Yes , the Zero W needs to be connected with wlan0 to another AP and be himself an AP with same SSID like the Hotspot-AP (zero acts like a reapeater).
There will be some applications running on the zero that will use wlan0 and there will be some devices that use the uap0 on the zero as ap to get in touch with services on the zero and one the original AP (Hotspot)

Answer (score 1):

In general you have two ways to use two or more interfaces: routing or bridging. As you already have found, bridging on Raspberry Pi is limited. For some use cases you can emulate bridging with proxy arp. But you use a virtual interface **uap0** that is derived from the only available physical interface **wlan0**. As far as I know there is no experience to use proxy arp on a virtual interface together with its own based physical interface. It may be possible but I suspect it will make trouble.

So I suggest to use routing. With it you can also get all services anywhere, on the RasPi, on your router, even on the whole world. How to setup a WiFi repeater using routing you can look at [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866). Please don't confuse the optional bridge with the WiFi client uplink to your remote internet router. That bridge is used parallel to the access point of the RasPi and bridges two different interfaces.