# Bridge WiFi with ethernet on RPi 3B+ without NAT

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-3b+

I would like to bridge eth0 and wlan0 on Raspberry Pi. The connections are as follows:

```
                 ________________________________________ 
                |                  RPi                   |
AP with DHCP --- eth0                               wlan0 --- Devices
                |________________________________________|
```

I would like RPi as well as other devices connected through it to get IP address from DHCP server, so the Raspberry Pi does not get involved. 
Do I have only to setup /etc/network/interfaces:

```
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
iface wlan0 inet manual

auto bridge
allow-hotplug wlan0

# Added by hostapd setup
allow-hotplug bridge
iface bridge inet dhcp
  bridge_ports wlan0 eth0
  wireless-power off
```

and hostapd to make Raspberry an AP?

Usual scenario is different:

```
                 ________________________________________ 
                |                  RPi                   |
AP with DHCP --- wlan0                               eth0 --- Devices
                |________________________________________|
```

I've read that in such scenario I have to additionaly use one of these approaches:

https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections

https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnectionsProxyArp

Does my use case need also these additional steps?

Comment: Check out this gist, it may help you. https://github.com/arpitjindal97/raspbian-recipes

Answer (score 2):

Just some general information first to understand the different setups. In the first setup you have an access point on the RasPi with interface **wlan0** that can other devices connect by WiFi. The wired interface **eth0** is connected as uplink to the internet router, no matter if it also has an access point. That isn't used in this case.
**The RasPi is an access point with a wired uplink.**

The second setup is just the other way around. The **wlan0** interface is connected as client to the internet router/access point by WiFi. Other devices are wired connected to the RasPi to interface **eth0**. If you want to connect more than one device you need an additional switch maybe with 5 or 8 or more wired ports.
**The RasPi is a router with a WiFi client uplink.**

You want to bridge interfaces **eth0** and **wlan0**. This is only possible in the first case. Bridging a WiFi client uplink as in the second case must be supported by the WiFi device but the built-in WiFi device of a Raspberry Pi don't do it. For details look at [Raspberry Pi WiFi to Ethernet Bridge for a server?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81518/79866).

For the first setup - bridging an access point with a wired port (uplink) - there are many tutorials available on the web. I prefer to use systemd-networkd and you can find one example at [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866). Use section *Setting up an access point with a bridge*.

For the second setup - using a wireless client uplink - there is a workaround available. You can emulate a bridge with **proxy arp**. How to do it you can look at [Workaround for a wifi bridge on a Raspberry Pi with proxy arp](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88955/79866).

Because your use case is the first setup, you do not need to use additional steps for proxy arp. Bridging the interfaces is part of the setup.