# Access point as WiFi router/repeater with bridge and additional WiFi-dongle

Tags: wifi, bridge

I have such a question I found a great @Ingo tutorial from this forum.
[Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95072/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-with-additional-wifi-dongle)
Therefore, I have a question.
I have an IP camera that creates a wifi hostspot at 192.168.43.1
Is it possible to connect to this camera as client wifi on wlan0 and then make a repeater on wlan1. So that I could connect to wlan1 by phone and make the stream application work.
Everywhere on the network there are descriptions of making APs in a different subnet. I care about the same subnet so that the android application works.
Unless you have some other idea how to redirect network traffic to 192.168.43.1 and traffic from camera to phone via wlan1 so that the original camera application works.
Thank you in advance for all the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That you only have found solutions with different subnets for the WiFi client connection and the access point has a reason. To have only one subnet, or also called one broadcast domain, you need to bridge the interface for the WiFi client connection with the interface for the access point. This must be supported by the hardware of the WiFi device, but the on-board WiFi device of a Raspberry Pi doesn't do it. So you can only use routing with different subnets. For further information about this you can have a look at [Raspberry Pi WiFi to Ethernet Bridge for a server?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81518/79866). But as you can read there, fortunately we have a workaround for this problem. You can use **proxy arp** as described at [Workaround for a wifi bridge on a Raspberry Pi with proxy arp](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88955/79866). The static configuration should best fit to your use case.