# wifi to ethernet trunk port

Tags: raspbian, ethernet, wireless, bridge

I have a location in a building where running an ethernet cable is just not possible.  I am looking for way to get a raspberry pi to connect wirelessly to one of the AP's and convert it to ethernet.  I would be plugging in the raspberry pi's ethernet to a 5 port managed switch.  The ethernet port on the raspberry pi as well as the wireless need to be configured as a trunk port.  My AP's can handle this, I just need help configuring the pi.  I dont need DHCP or anything, I need this to be on the same LAN as my other equipment.  So a transparent bridge.

LAN -> Wireless AP -> Wireless Pi -> Ethernet Pi - Switch

The Pi should not manipulate the ethernet or wireless traffic, All I need it to is just to send whatever comes in out the wireless or ethernet interface.

I have read several articles but they include maserading the ip's which I dont need.

Could someone help me come up with a solution?

Comment: Have a look at https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-wifi-bridge/  - set the IP ranges on the dhcp servers on the WiFi and Ethernet so the ranges do not clash :)

Comment: @Andyroo The headline of the link you have given is lying. They do not create a bridge, they set ip forwarding.

Answer (score 3):

You want to have a client WiFi connection to an uplink access point. The problem is, that a Raspberry Pi does not support bridging a WiFi interface used for a client connection due to a hardware limitation. For further information about this look at [Raspberry Pi WiFi to Ethernet Bridge for a server?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81518/79866).

But as noted there you can use [**proxy arp** as a workaround for a bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88955/79866). I suggest to use section **Static configuration of proxy arp** because it is simpler and just right for your use case.

Comment: I have followed the Proxy ARP workaround solution, but it is not working as expected.  when I connect my ethernet cable to the pi I get 169.254.X.X, but the pi itself does have the same IP on eth0 as the wifi.  the only difference is that it is a /32 not a /24 as the wifi.  I would need it to be a /24 since I will be plugging in 3-4 hosts of the ethernet port.  I followed the Dynamic Proxy not the static one, since I will be connecting multiple devices and sometimes they might need to be unplugged.

Comment: @user2236794 The dynamic configuration is only made to have a **mobile Raspberry PI** to connect to different WiFi uplink access points (e.g. in different hotels) and mainly connect one wired connected device to the internet. It has nothing to do with changing devices on your switch. As far as I understand your RasPi isn't carried around, so you should use the static configuration. It should support different wired connected devices.