# Use Pi as Ethernet Bridge to SSH into wireless device

Tags: wifi, ethernet

I basically have a device that I need to SSH into but it can only be connected by Ethernet.

I want to set up a Raspberry Pi so that I can use it as a bridge to provide the device with connection to the network but also to be able to ssh into that device, i.e. provide it an IP address on my local network.

I have managed to get the internet to work through the Ethernet but only the Pi shows up on the network not the device.

Comment: And an alternative solution https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88954/workaround-for-a-wifi-bridge-on-a-raspberry-pi-with-proxy-arp/88955#88955

Comment: @MatsK I will try that alternate solution, thanks! It's unfortunate that the first link suggests it might not be possible :(